# Rewrite URL using Apache for redirecting root domain

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this scenario where I would like to redirect my domains using the following scenario. Can you please advice if this can be achieved using RewriteRule in Apache?

I would like to redirect any calls made using http://www.domainname.com/url to redirect to http://domainname.com/url.

I was able to achieve the above using the following rewrite rule

```
# BEGIN WithoutWWW
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domainname\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domainname.com/$1 [R=301,L]
# END WithoutWWW
```

If anyone tries to visit just http://www.domainname.com or http://domainname.com, I would like them to redirect to http://dname.com

How can I achieve this rule using RewriteRule in Apache?
I'm also using PHP, so a solution using PHP would be valid too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your combined .htaccess with your existing and new code:

```
RewriteEngine on

# redirect domainname.com/ or www.domainname.com/ to dname.com/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domainname\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://dname.com [R=301,L]

# append www to domainname.com    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domainname\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://domainname.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domainname.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: not sure if you understood my question. I want http://www.domainname.com/url to be redirected to http://domainname.com/url.

But if anyone visits just the root domain (http://domainname.com or http://www.domainname.com [no /url]), then it needs to redirect to http://dname.com

I wish to combine both the rules.

Answer (score 0):

That example looks like mod_rewrite.
With mod_rewrite you could do:

```
# BEGIN WithoutWWW
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domainname\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://dname.com/$1 [R=301,L]
# END WithoutWWW
```

You may want to look at http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite

Based on your comment you want to redirect the root differently so we could do:

```
RewriteEngine on
#www.domainname.com & domainname.com -> dname.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domainname\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://dname.com/ [R=301,L]

#www.domainname.com/[url] -> domainname.com/[url]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domainname\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domainname.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: not sure if you understood my question. I want http://www.domainname.com/url to be redirected to http://domainname.com/url.

But if anyone visits just the root domain (http://domainname.com or http://www.domainname.com [no /url]), then it needs to redirect to http://dname.com

I wish to combine both the rules.