# Azure VM: Custom domain without www

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have found a lot of similar questions, but all of them are in regards to a web-app in Azure, while what I am after is virtual machine.
I have only VM setup in Azure and on that VM I have Apache HTTPD. I updated A records for my domain to VM's IP and added CNAME for *.cloudapp.net, and even CNAMEs for asverify.*.azurewebsites.net and awverify.*.azurewebsites.net (using my service name instead of *, of course).
And it works fine if I go to www subdomain, but not to the root domain. From manuals found online I see, that you need to setup domains in Azure itself, too, but I fail to find such options for Virtual Machine. I see similar option for Blob, but I'm not sure if it has any relevance here.

Can someone advise, what else I may be needing to connect to my VM using a root domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't an azure specific issue, you need to configure Apache correctly with rewrites.  See this answer: [Rewrite URL using Apache for redirecting root domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017224/rewrite-url-using-apache-for-redirecting-root-domain)

Comment: nope. this is not it. Apache is configured to redirect everything to domain.com. When the same configuration is used on my own PC it works fine. On azure domain.com is unavailable while www.domain.com is disregarding whether I add www in Apache config or not

Comment: hm... actually you were right. turned out I missed one line where I had to add www to a redirect